# What does os.sep do in this function?

Tags: python, file, operating-system

```
def list_files(startpath):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath):
        # print(dirs)
        if dir!= '.git':
            level = root.replace(startpath, '').count(os.sep)
            indent = ' ' * 4 * (level)
            print('{}{}/'.format(indent, os.path.basename(root)))
            subindent = ' ' * 4 * (level + 1)
            for f in files:
                print('{}{}'.format(subindent, f))
```

Please I don't understand how the     level = root.replace(startpath, '').count(os.sep) works,  please I'd appreciate a detailed explanation.

Comment: `os.sep` is a cross platform way to get the path separator.

Comment: Do you know what `replace` does? Do you know what `count` does? Do you know what `os.sep` is?

Comment: From the documentation - `os.sep` - The character used by the operating system to separate pathname components. This is '/' for POSIX and '\\' for Windows.

Comment: Check the documentation for python count().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About `os.sep` from the [Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html)

> `The character used by the operating system to separate pathname components. This is '/' for POSIX and '\' for Windows.`

And from `help(str.count)`:

> ```
> Help on method_descriptor:
>
> count(...)
>    S.count(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int
>
>    Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in
>    string S[start:end].  Optional arguments start and end are
>    interpreted as in slice notation.
> ```

So it returns number of path seperators in the path string.